# Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a drop down menu and choose an option. I am using the latest version of Selenium, the latest version of Firefox, the latest version of geckodriver, and the latest version of Python.

Here is my issue: When I try to choose an option, it gives me the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view.
```

I have tried various ways to circumnavigate this issue, but none seem to work. Here are some of the approaches I tried.

```
mySelectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('providerTypeDropDown')
dropDownMenu = Select(mySelectElement)
dropDownMenu.select_by_visible_text('Professional')

mySelectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('providerTypeDropDown')
dropDown = Select(mySelectElement)
for option in dropDown.options:
    message = option.get_attribute('innerText')
    print(message)
    if message == 'Professional':
        print("Exists")
        dropDown.select_by_visible_text(message) 
        break

element = browser.find_element_by_id('providerTypeDropDown')
browser.execute_script("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", element, "Professional")
```

The HTML code follows the usual select tags and option tags. Any help is appreciated. The HTML code is included below.

```
<select data-av-chosen="providerTypes" id="providerTypeDropDown" data-placeholder="Please Select a Provider Type" name="providerTypeDropDown"
class="chzn-select input-full ng-pristine chzn-done ng-invalid ng-invalid-provider-type" data-ng-options="providerType.value for providerType in request.models.providerTypes"
data-ng-model="request.models.providerType" data-av-validator-field="providerType" data-disable-search-threshold="5" style="display; none;">
    <option value="" class="">Please Select a Provider Type</option>
    <option value="0">Professional</option>
    <option value="1">Institutional</option>
</select>
```

The print statements are there for testing/code tracing purposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view.
```

...implies that the `<option>` item which your program was trying to interact with could not be scrolled into view.

The *HTML* of the desired element would have given us some idea behind the error. However it seems the desired element was not `clickable` / within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). To address the issue you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
mySelectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('providerTypeDropDown')
dropDownMenu = Select(mySelectElement)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='providerTypeDropDown']//options[contains(.,'Professional')]")))
dropDownMenu.select_by_visible_text('Professional')
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: Hello, this still gives me a TimeOut Exception. I have added the HTML snippet if it helps further.

Comment: Hello! I figured it out using ActionChains. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Srikanth Does the above mean that the selected answer did not actually solve your problem?

Comment: @dre, at least does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a wait:

```
mySelectElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "providerTypeDropDown")))
mySelectElement.click()
```

it will wait at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable and then click.

Also I don't see in your code, that you click on the dropdown button, which opens dropdown menu. Locate this button, also add a wait and click on it before you select the option. Hope it helps.

Note: for this code you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hello, this still gives me a TimeOut Exception. I have added the HTML snippet if it helps further.

Comment: Hello! I figured it out using ActionChains. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Srikanth can you share your solution here please

Comment: For future readers of this thread. Mouse-over with Selenium python bindings (stackoverflow.com/a/8261754/9083077) describes the soltuion with ActionChains.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Where I was unable to select a dropdown value with selectByValue, selectByIndex and selectByVisible text. I tried actions class and scrollBy using Javascript executor also. Nothing worked. After 1 day of trial and error, I came up with the below workaround,

```
public static void selectDropDownByVisibleText(WebElement element, String text){
        waitForPageLoad();
        String firstCharacterDropDownVal = ""+text.charAt(0);
        HashSet<String> uniqueDropDownVals = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            Select select = new Select(element);
            select.selectByVisibleText(text);
        }catch (ElementNotInteractableException e){
            Select select = new Select(element);
            while(!select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text) &&
                    uniqueDropDownVals.add(select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText())) {
                element.sendKeys(firstCharacterDropDownVal);
            }
        }
        log.info("Selected dropdown by visible text "+text);
    }


public static void waitForPageLoad() {
        log.debug("Waiting for page to get loaded..");
        new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(FIND_ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME)).
                ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).
                until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
        log.debug("Page loaded successfully");
    }
```

I will explain the working. First it will try to select by visible text. If we get the exception it will enter inside the catch block. There we are sending the first character of the desired text on the dropdown webelement. So the dropdown element changes. Let's say the dropdown values are Apple,Aeroplane,Adam and I want to select Adam. First time I send 'A' on the webelement the dropdown changes to Apple. Then I add it to the HashSet and check whether the selected element is the desired element. if it matches then we break out of the while loop. If the same element is added twice, then the HashSet add method will return false. This will break us out of the while loop and keep us from entering into an infinite loop. So each time I enter 'A' the dropdown value changes to the next value that starts with 'A'. This is the approach.