# How to select an option from a dropdown menu through partial text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu

I'm using the Selenium Kit in Python and am trying to select an option from a drop-down menu.

For this I'm using `python driver.select_by_visible_text()` .
My problem is now that the visible text always contains the value I'm looking but with something added afterwards. The `select_by_visible_text()` just finds the exact option, but I can´t name it exactly.

For example: I'm looking for the option "W33", the website then says "W33 (only 4 left)". I would like to select "W33 (only 4 left)", but don´t know how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get a list of all options with the `options` attribute on your `Select` object:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('myselect')
elem_select = Select(elem)
opts = elem_select.options
```

Then, check which of them matches. In your example, check the `text` attribute:

```
opts_to_select = [o for o in opts if o.text.startswith('W33')]
my_option = opts_to_select[0] # select first match
                              # (Maybe you also want to raise an error if 
                              # there is more than one match.)
```

And select it:

```
if not my_elem.is_selected():
    my_elem.click()
```

Source: [`Select` at selenium-python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select)

Comment: Why was this downvoted, is there something wrong? It answers the question and is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As the static part of the *visible text* i.e. `W33` is always followed by a *variable text*, e.g. `(only 4 left)`, `(only 3 left)`, etc, so  [`select_by_visible_text()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_visible_text) may not be effective. You may have to consider either among:

- [select_by_value(value)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value)
- [select_by_index(index)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_index)

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select//option[contains(., 'W33')]").click()
```

> Note: You may need to expand the `<select>` element first before clicking on the option.

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select//option[contains(., 'W33')]"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175)