# UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div> error selecting a country using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to **scrape** the in iterative scatter plot.
Before doing that, I want to change the country, but I fail to select the country I want.

Website link:
https://vizhub.healthdata.org/tobacco/

The error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedTagNameException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-fa99f3a62600> in <module>
      1 cc=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="location_id"]')
----> 2 select_English=Select(cc)
      3 #select_English.select_by_visible_text('English (GB)')

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py in __init__(self, webelement)
     37             raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
     38                 "Select only works on <select> elements, not on <%s>" %
---> 39                 webelement.tag_name)
     40         self._el = webelement
     41         multi = self._el.get_attribute("multiple")

UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>
```

I copied the xpath from the website which shows that it's a select element.

Here is my code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
chrome_optionsme = Options()
chrome_optionsme.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_optionsme.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_optionsme, 
                          executable_path="path/chromedriver")
url="https://vizhub.healthdata.org/tobacco/"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="data"]').click()
cc=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="location_id"]')
select_English=Select(cc)
```

Secondly, how to extract iterative plots' data using selenium?

Comment: There's also `<div class="control" id="location_id">` which comes before your select element. You can always use `//select[@id='location_id']`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel after using the code you provided, I try to select China, it fails. ```select_English.select_by_visible_text('China')``` with the error: ```NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: China```

Comment: Most likely because the element is not visible. In fact, the select element itself has `style="display: none"`. This indicates that you need to make the select element visible usually by clicking on some other element such as a tab or a button somewhere.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel After adding the code ```cc.click()``` it shows the error ```ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)``` As I click it manually, it is blank.

Comment: Yes because the select element is hidden (display: none). You'll need to interact with the elements within the `//div[@id='s2id_location_id']`

Comment: what happens if you do print(len(Select(//select[@id='location_id'])) ????

Comment: @AdrianJimenez it shows the error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'```

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Could you show me how to interact with the elements within the ```//div[@id='s2id_location_id']```? Should I click it first, and then?

Comment: That would be too much work for me at the moment. You'll have to mimic what you as a user would be clicking on and typing text into. For example, you'll first need to click on the "countries" tab then in the div with id=s2id_location_id, there's a div which when clicked brings up some other elements, one of which is a text entry element where you can type China.

Comment: How do you _change the country_? Which element do I have to click?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thank you for your guide, selenium is blocked by this website. But I saw your answer below with using requests. Do you know how to extract the value from graphs? instead of the value of coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The select element is a placeholder. The clicks and other events are handled by other elements.

Perhaps you can bypass the HTML altogether. The following returns a sizable JSON.

```
import requests

import json

CHINA = 6

url = 'https://vizhub.healthdata.org/tobacco/php/getCountryData.php'

r = requests.post(url, data={'location_id': CHINA})

d = json.loads(r.content)

print(d)
```

Comment: That works! But how to get the real value in the graph instead of the coordinates/axes value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>
```

...implies that your program invoked [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python/62735660#62735660) on a `<div>` element, where as [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175) works only with [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tags.

---

### Solution

The *Country* dropdown within the website https://vizhub.healthdata.org/tobacco/ can be accessed through:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  a.select2-choice>span
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  //a[@class='select2-choice']/span
  ```

Snapshot:

[image: country]

So to select **China** from the *Country* dropdown a possible solution should have been:

```
driver.get("https://vizhub.healthdata.org/tobacco/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='data']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='select2-choice']/span"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='select2-results']//div[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='China']"))).click()
```

---

### tl; dr

However, the solution didn't work at my end and when I went ahead and inspected the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* it was observed that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **dist**. As an example:

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/ihme-ui@0.34.0/dist/ihme-ui.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/clipboard@1.7.1/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>`
- `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ihme-ui@0.34.0/dist/ihme-ui.css">`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* gets detected and subsequently gets **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: Hi Mr. DebanjanB, thank you for replying to my question again.  So it blocks bot scraping.  ```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='select2-results']//div[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='China']"))).click()``` Could you tell me where this path comes from? The other person who replies to this using requests, which could scrape content from the page successfully. Is that mean requests has less limitation than selenium?

Comment: @JoanMok If you browse manually you can verify each element in the DevTools. I would like to avoid any comment about requests,but from Selenium perspective the navigation was getting blocked due to Distil.