# Selenium , Automation, webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I have web application,It works only in edge browser with IE mode.In that I am unable to automate drop-down field,So I need code to automate the drop-down field using selenium web driver.

Comment: You muyst provide a [Minimum Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for someone to take a look at the issue and provide a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252175/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) discussion helps you?

Comment: I am using selectByVisibleText method

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what are you looking for...
I wrote it in C#.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI
    
IWebElement dropdownElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("country code"));

//create select element object 
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(dropdownElement);

//select by value
selectElement.SelectByValue("NIR"); 

// select by text
selectElement.SelectByText("Northern Ireland");
```

Comment: @Testing are you using a IDE?

Comment: @Testing however it is the same, the only thing that changes are the names of the methods, which instead of starting with an uppercase letter start with a lowercase one.
First you have to import the selenium support library, so is something like 'import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select'

Comment: I tired your code its not working

Comment: Yes I am using IDE

Comment: It depends on the web application front end technology, I might be wrong but no one give you the desired answer without seeing some code, error, HTML.

Comment: @Testing can you paste some HTML code here of the dropdown element?

Comment: @AlexandruBucur As I mentioned above our application work In Edge browser with IE mode there Right click is disabled we cannot inspect element, So I can't get HTML code.

Comment: @Testing shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+J on Windows, CMD+OPT+J on Mac

Comment: @AlexandruBucur I did that, I am getting "Developer tools are not available in internet explorer mode to debug the page open the page in IEChooser"

Comment: <select name="country code" onkeypress="return entermethod (submitprivatesearch) id=(privatecountry ) class=" input" ><option value="GER"> - - please select -- </option> <option value="GER">Germany</option><option value ="NIR">Northern Ireland</option>

Comment: @Testing I have modified my answer in order to select Northern Ireland from the select element: first retrieve the web element by name (in this case, the select element's name is country code), then there are 2 ways that do basically the same thing, the first one selects the Norther Ireland option by option value, the second one by the text. try it and let me know.

Comment: @AlexandruBucuri wrote below code
WebElement obj = getObject(strLocator);
Select dd = new Select(obj);
try{ 
dd.selectByVisibleText(value);
}catch(Expection e){
dd.selectByVisibleText(Value.toUpperCase());
} 
This is not working because Value is "Northern Ireland" as first letter is capital and rest small its failing and also I tired to remove try and catch and wrote dd.selectByVisibleText(Northern Ireland)
It throws Nosuchmethodexception.